# Rabbi Mordechai Eliyahu’s writings

Tags: jewish-books, rabbis, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, responsa, acharonim

Is there a source online for halachic writings of Rabbi [Mordechai Eliyahu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_Eliyahu) zt’’l? He was a Sephardic chief rabbi, did he publish any books of Halacha or responsa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read most of his books online for **free** on his website, HaRav.org.
https://harav.org/sfarim/

Comment: Nice find! Did not know that it was online

Answer (score 3):

שאלות ותשובות הרב הראשי (שו"ת הרב הראשי) (Shaalos UTeshuvos HaRav HaRashi), a responsa, can be bought for example [here](http://www.harav.co.il/product/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9). The blurb says that it is a collection of answers given to various halachic questions proposed to the Rav over the years.

> במשך שנות כהונתו ברבנות של מרן הראשון לציון הרב מרדכי אליהו, התקבלו בלשכתו אלפי פניות
> מהציבור הרחב בארץ ובעולם, שאלות בתחומי ההלכה השונים ובענייני השקפה ומוסר. חלק מהפניות נעשו בע"פ, וחלק ניכר מהפניות נעשו בכתב. שו"ת הרב הראשי מתייחד בקיצור הדברים ומביא את השורה התחתונה בפסיקה. דיונים הלכתיים שאפשר היה להאריך ולהעמיק בהם תומצתו ע"י
> הרב לכלל שורות ספורות המציגות את המסקנה ההלכתית למעשה.
> בספרים שו"ת הרב הראשי מוגשות מבחר של שאלות ותשובות שהופנו לרב בעת כהונתו כרב ראשי לישראל

[image]

It can also be bought at:

- [שו"ת הרב הראשי / הרב מרדכי אליהו זצ"ל](https://shop.mishna.org.il/products/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99-%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95-%D7%96%D7%A6%D7%9C)
- [Hbooks](https://www.hbooks.co.il/product/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99--%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99-%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95-%D7%96%D7%A6%D7%9C) (see there for inside-pictures of the sefer).

As far as I know, I did a quick search, the sefer isn't viewable online.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Mordecai Eliyahu's guide to Taharat haMishpacha is the go-to khallah guide for [English-speaking Sephardic Jews](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HMTDFJO) and [French-speaking Jews of all backgrounds.](https://www.nli.org.il/en/books/NNL_ALEPH990055552120205171/NLI)